# Include only required font icons in prod

Tags: angular, sass, build, font-awesome

I would like to use Font Awesome, but only few icons will be needed. The project is in Angular 10 and I'm using SCSS.

Is it possible to install Font Awesome as dev dependency and then only import the icons that I'll need in my `_vendors.scss` stylesheet? (I'm following [7.1 pattern](https://sass-guidelin.es/#the-7-1-pattern) with SCSS structure). I have done something similar with bootstrap, where I only imported grid and necessary variables and mixins.